# Why the items are not in center of the page (margin:auto)

Tags: html, css, margin

I have this html code

```
<section id="ItemsContainer">
    <div id="FirstItem">
        This is First Item
    </div>
    <div id="SecondItem">
        This is Second Item
    </div>
</section>
```

and this is my css style

```
#FirstItem, #SecondItem {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

    #FirstItem *, #SecondItem * {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    #ItemsContainer {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 500px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #FirstItem, #SecondItem {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
    }
}
```

and this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/AJUsA/1/) of the code

the problem is they are in center of the page but not exactly in center of the page. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `#ItemsContainer` width `500px`, each div inside width `200px`. Increase width to `240px` each child div and they will be centered :)

Comment: you need to give a width to `#FirstItem, #SecondItem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set `#ItemsContainer` to `500px` wide, but the two elements inside it don't make up that same width. If you calculate `2 * 200px`, plus `5px` padding on both sides of each, that's `420px`. Changing `#ItemsContainer` to `420px` seems to do the trick, *or* you can adjust the width of your first and second item to make a grand total of `500px`.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/AJUsA/1/

Only changes I made were:

```
#ItemsContainer {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}

#FirstItem, #SecondItem {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    width:240px;
}
```

I added the float on `#ItemsContainer` to give it height but ideally you'd probably use a clearfix class for that.